# Hash size: Are prime numbers "near" powers of two a poor choice for the modulus?

Tags: hash

Cormen et al.'s "Introduction to Algorithms" says the following about the division method hash function $h(k)=k \text{ mod } m$:

> A prime not too close to an exact power of 2 is often a good choice for $m$. For example, suppose we wish to allocate a hash table, with collisions resolved by chaining, to hold roughly $n=2000$ character strings, where a character has 8 bits. We don't mind examining an average of 3 elements in an unsuccesful search, so we allocate a table of size $m=701$. The number $701$ is chose because it is a prime near $2000/3$ but **not near any power of 2**.

The book, however, does not explain what it means by "near". Is $701$ preferrable over, say, $661$ because $661-512<701-512$? I do not understand how this is relevant to the modulo function involved in the calculation of $h(k)$.

Answer (score 2):

If a string of 8 bit bytes is interpreted as a large integer, and you calculate the value modulo $2^{24}-1$ then the first, fourth, seventh byte etc. are all hashed to the same value, which means the hash will not be well distributed.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86340/82683) possibly explains why choosing M(table size) equal to a power of 2 should be avoided.

> Prime numbers that are too close to a power of 2 will provide the
> same kind of biasing as a power of 2 for the keys which differs by
> $+a$ or $-a$ if $2^k=a(modulo)M$.

In division method we simply use remainder modulo M: ***h(K) = K mod M***

In this case some values of M are obviously much better than others.

**Case 1:**
If M is an even number h(K) will be even when K is even and odd when K is odd, and this will lead to a substantial bias in many files.

**Case 2:**
It would be even worse to let M be a power of 2 (more generally the radix of the computer), since K mod M would then be simply the least significant digits of K (independent of the other digits).

**Case 3:**
Similarly we can argue that M probably shouldn't be a multiple of 3: for if the keys are alphabetic, two keys that differ only by the permutation of letters, would then differ in numeric value by a multiple of 3. (This occurs because *$2^{2n}$ mod 3 = 1* and *$10^n$ mod 3 = 1*).

> **Case 4:** In general, we want to avoid values of M that divide $r^k+a$ or $r^k-a$, where k and a are small numbers and r is the radix
> of the alphabetic charecter set (usually $r=64, \ 256$ or $100$),
> since a remainder modulo such a value of M tends to be largely a
> simple superposition of key digits. Such considerations suggest that
> we choose M to be a prime number such that $r^k!=a(modulo)M$ or
> $r^k!=-a(modulo)M$ for small k & a.
>
> ***--Donald E. Knuth** (The art of Computer Programming Vol. 3)*

Comment: There are very few primes that are powers of two, and the question was already based on the assumption that the table size is a prime.

Comment: @gnasher729 Please take a look, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Goo you this quote from Knuth, but question why still remains.

Comment: @Yola I have mentioned that it gives the same kind of biasing as a power of 2, if you have got the case with powers of 2 then its easy to understand this.